# plt.show() (import matplotlib.pyplot as plt) does not show plot

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, zipline

I have Python 3.5 installed with zipline and matplotlib via conda, there are no errors are being thrown out, but the graph isn't showing so I'm not sure what is wrong with it?

Let me know if you want me to post any additional information, the code is below:

```
from zipline.api import order_target, record, symbol
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def initialize(context):
    context.i = 0
    context.asset = symbol('AAPL')


def handle_data(context, data):
    # Skip first 300 days to get full windows
    context.i += 1
    if context.i < 300:
        return

    # Compute averages
    # data.history() has to be called with the same params
    # from above and returns a pandas dataframe.
    short_mavg = data.history(context.asset, 'price', bar_count=100, frequency="1d").mean()
    long_mavg = data.history(context.asset, 'price', bar_count=300, frequency="1d").mean()

    # Trading logic
    if short_mavg > long_mavg:
        # order_target orders as many shares as needed to
        # achieve the desired number of shares.
        order_target(context.asset, 100)
    elif short_mavg < long_mavg:
        order_target(context.asset, 0)

    # Save values for later inspection
    record(AAPL=data.current(context.asset, 'price'),
           short_mavg=short_mavg,
           long_mavg=long_mavg)


def analyze(context, perf):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
    perf.portfolio_value.plot(ax=ax1)
    ax1.set_ylabel('portfolio value in $')

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
    perf['AAPL'].plot(ax=ax2)
    perf[['short_mavg', 'long_mavg']].plot(ax=ax2)

    perf_trans = perf.ix[[t != [] for t in perf.transactions]]
    buys = perf_trans.ix[[t[0]['amount'] > 0 for t in perf_trans.transactions]]
    sells = perf_trans.ix[
        [t[0]['amount'] < 0 for t in perf_trans.transactions]]
    ax2.plot(buys.index, perf.short_mavg.ix[buys.index],
             '^', markersize=10, color='m')
    ax2.plot(sells.index, perf.short_mavg.ix[sells.index],
             'v', markersize=10, color='k')
    ax2.set_ylabel('price in $')
    plt.legend(loc=0)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you call the functions somewhere?

Comment: This was the example code given by Zipline (https://www.zipline.io/beginner-tutorial.html#ipython-notebook) -- with their notebook outputting the graphs.

Comment: Hi. Can you please add the command that is being used to run this? e.g. 

%%zipline --start 2014-1-1 --end 2018-1-1 -o dma.pickle --no-benchmark